# Upgraded to 22.04.2 LTS, now VLC can't open RTSP stream

Tags: 22.04, vlc, rtsp

After upgrading, I can no longer open a stream to my security camera (`rtsp://frontcam2/`). This worked fine before the upgrade. I can open mpeg files and audio and video work fine on those.

I turned on debug messages, and I got

```
main debug: net: connecting to frontcam2 port 554
main debug: connection succeeded (socket = 17)
access_realrtsp warning: Cseq mismatch, got 1, assumed 0
access_realrtsp debug: rtsp connected
access_realrtsp warning: only real/helix rtsp servers supported for now
```

Comment: maybe related: https://github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx/issues/223

Answer (score 5):

Try the snap version or build vlc with the --enable-live555 config item.  See https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=161400 , the claim was ubuntu stopped supporting rtsp out of the box.

Comment: The snap version gets the desktop version, but unfortunately it doesn't include cvlc, which I use for saving the last few days of security camera footage.